# Doubt about Carathéodory uniqueness

Tags: measure-theory

In Measure Theory we covered Carathéodory's extension theorem. The proof I've been given proves exactly the following 3-point statement.

> **Caratheeodory extension theorem**
>
> Suppose $\mu$ is a positive $\sigma$-additive functional on a ring $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$, where "ring" means it's closed under finite intersections and unions, and under relative complement, and I think it should contain the empty set, but it sure need not contain $X$. Let $\mathcal{E}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ be the least $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$. Then the following hold:
>
> 1. The outer measure $\mu^\ast(E)=\inf\{\sum\mu(A_j):\bigcup_jA_j\supseteq E,\{A_j\}_j\subseteq\mathcal{A}\}$ gives an extension of $\mu$ to a measure (positive $\sigma$-additive functional) on $\mathcal{E}$ (perhaps under suitable extra hypotheses I won't deal with since they are irrelevant to the post and I haven't reviewed that part of the proof yet);
> 2. If there are two *finite* extensions like in 1, then they are equal on all $\mathcal{E}$; i.e., there exists *at most one finite* such extension;
> 3. If there are two *$\sigma$-finite* such extension, they coincide; that is, there exists *at most one $\sigma$-finite* such extension.

What I was wondering about is: is it possible to find a case where $\mu$ has two distinct extensions, one finite and the other $\sigma$-finite? Surely if $X\in\mathcal{A}$, as is the case in most applications (most notably Lebesgue measure), then it is impossible, since $\mu$ is defined on $X$. But what if $X\notin\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: A finite extension is a special case of $\sigma$-finite extension. So you can not have two distinct extensions, one finite and the other $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Please note that the result you post is about extensions built from the outer measure. If we were talking about extensions in general then the original measure $\mu$ must be $\sigma$-finite to ensure uniqueness of extension to $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: @Ramiro but if we are assuming the extension is $\sigma$-finite, does that not imply the original $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite too? I should have written that $\mu$ had to be $\sigma$-finite for the proof, but if the extension is, can $\mu$ not be?

Comment: The extension being $\sigma$-finite does NOT ensure the original $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Ramiro that is interesting. I would have asked for an example of that, but this veers off-topic from this post, which is why I asked [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709297/example-of-sigma-finite-extension-to-non-sigma-finite-functional) specifically about that.

Comment: Concerning this question, will you convert that comment to an answer? I guess I was just missing that.

Comment: Here is an exemple. Let $X$ be $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$.  Let $\mathcal{A}$ be defined as 
$$
\mathcal{A}=\{C\subseteq \mathbb{N} \:|\: C \textrm { is finite } \} \cup \{D\cup \{\infty\} \:|\: \mathbb{N} \setminus D \textrm { is finite}  \} 
$$
It is easy to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a ring (in fact, an algebra). Consider $\mu$ the counting measure defined on $\mathcal{A}$. Then, $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. (CONTINUE)

Comment: But $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=P(X)$. For each $r$ non-negative (finite) real number, let $\nu_r$ be the measure defined on $P(X)$ by $\nu_r(\{a\})=1$, if $a\neq \infty$ and $\nu_r(\{\infty\})=r$. All those $\nu_r$ measures (there are uncountable of them) are $\sigma$-finite extensions of $\mu$.

Comment: Note that none of the $\nu_r$ extensions "come from" the outer measure $\mu^*$.

Comment: Indeed. The outer measure $\mu^\ast$ satisfies $\mu^\ast(\{\infty\})=\infty$, since coverings of $\{\infty\}$ have to be infinite sets and thus have infinite $\mu$. RIght?

Comment: Yes. It is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finite extension is a special case of $\sigma$-finite extension. So you can not have two distinct extensions, one finite and the other $\sigma$-finite.

Remark:  $\mu^*$ always produces just one extension of $\mu$ no matter if the extension (or $\mu$) is finite or $\sigma$-finite or not. So item 2 and item 3 in the question can be replace by the simple statement that: the  $\mu^*$ always produces just one extension of $\mu$ (even when $\mu$ has multiple extensions).